# Firebase onDisconnect gets fired when iPhone sleeps

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Any idea as to why Firebase onDisconnect is fired whenever my iPhone sleeps/I tap the power button to put it to sleep? I have background data enabled and when I send it to the background it doesn't get fired.

I have the same code running on Android with a service and it doesn't get called when I hit the sleep/power button.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach an `onDisconnect` handler, the write operation will be executed when the server determines that the client has disconnected. This can happen either when the client explicitly closes the connection or when the socket times out. To prevent unwanted time outs, the Firebase client send regular keep-alive packets.

Most likely iOS is keeping the client from sending such keep-alive packets after a while or it is in some other way closing the socket.